# ajax header authentication error: HTTP status code 401

Tags: json, ajax, passwords, authorization, http-status-code-401

I'm trying to get some data from a REST interface from an ajax call.

My code looks like this:

```
var request = {
        url: "https://ZZZZ",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        accepts: "application/json",
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("XXXX:YYYY"));
        },
        error: function(jqXHR) {
            console.log("ajax error " + jqXHR.status);
        }
    };
```

If I'm running it I get this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load "URL". Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401

which indicates something with my authentication is not working properly.

If I manually go to the page https://ZZZZ and enter username XXXX and password YYYY in the field shown below it works.

[image]

Where is my fault?

Comment: Do your credentials need Base64 encoding and decoding? this error is normally from bad credentials

Comment: Yes it does, when connecting from Java and encoding to Base64 it works

Comment: I am not expert but I was seeking by my question if you already tried `"Basic XXXX:YYYY"`, because from my humble opinion, your request didn't yet reach the server so that java intercept it and encode credentials for comparison with stored one. If I am wrong please to correct me I am also a newbie

Comment: Yes I also tried it without ase64 encoding but didn't worked